# Python Selenium - href Attribute outputs a false link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, href, element

Im using Selenium to extract a href elements under div class elements from comments on Facebook posts.

To do that im using **https://m.** and not **https://www.**

The weird thing is that the code is working but it produces a **wrong href link**.

This is my test link:
https://m.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10158970984237798&id=267767252797

here's the relevant sample from the code:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2b1h async_elem']/a")
for link in links:
   print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

This is the first print **(wrong)**:

> https://m.facebook.com/comment/replies/?ctoken=10158970984237798_10158971018182798&count=7&curr&pc=1&isinline&initcomp&ft_ent_identifier=10158970984237798&eav=**AfYL7kFupIufaUdT64Uj85QVZhOZxYUkTTY1wrjRnMqxFG85Nmev-Au_bPm0a4Z0HzM&av=100078743166486&gfid=AQC0Hgp2a-I6Q7Fpj_Y&**tn**=R**

but the href link should be **(Right)**:

> https://m.facebook.com/comment/replies/?ctoken=10158970984237798_10158971018182798&count=7&curr&pc=1&isinline&initcomp&ft_ent_identifier=10158970984237798&eav=**AfaIC6mT5kvBUEIfgoLYj9G5KYF_lv4sncnOMaJjJKk1dEk-aXbNnYwwNnoFmt9kIOQ&av=100000431416784&gfid=AQDiD_GY8uckLbNf0bQ&**tn**=R**

Why does this piece of code get the wrong href link?

Comment: What is wrong with the link? They look pretty much the same.

Comment: I've highlighted the part where the links get changed.
the things is - it pulls the href link, the code works. But it pulls the wrong link. i've looked for the "false" link in the html and couldn't find it.

Comment: Why do you consider one link to be "right" and one "wrong"? Is one from your manual browsing session and one from your script? Have you verified the HTML your script is actually receiving from Facebook? Facebook may actually returning a different link to you. For example tracking data based on your user agent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
I did try it from a different user and it gave me the wrong link again (same link) but i will try to scrap the entire HTML and look for the links there.
Ill update the question if necessary

Comment: hey @BillyHudson, it appears that the code was perfectly fine. so i searched if there is something that FB does to block scraping their site.. I found that there is something, look at my Answer. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone looking for a solution to the same problem I had, i will save you the trouble and say that after a lot of digging, it appears that FB is simply changing several elements values (like href..) after a varied short period of time (can be hours or minutes).

in my case, the code worked only with 30 min gap between runs.

FYI,
Peace.